# Interactive use of Datashader with matplotlib, 1.8 billion point array

Tags: python, visualization, holoviews, datashader, pyviz

I am working with geophysical data so now I have a 400k*512 "pixel" dataset that basically is "scans" times "samples".

The data exists as np array of the dimension mentioned above.

I need to visualize it interactively with zoom and all.

I found Datashader and holoviews, but I can't figure out how to connect both for data that is rastered already.

I figured out
https://datashader.org/user_guide/Grids.html

and it works well for generating a shaded picture within my Spyder console.

https://datashader.org/getting_started/Interactivity.html
suggests using holoviews, but it only provides an example for doing so with point data.

Trying to use matplotlib I can't figure out what glypj to give to dsshow so it will use my array data.

I am a bit lost here and would be very thankful for help.